React App accessing ABP.IO Swagger Endpoint returns CORS-Errors (OpenIddict)
After years of MVC I'm doing my first react app and feel like I'm a toddler.
I'm trying to access my ABP.IO Swagger API.
The Url works fine and returns json data correctly, when I try it through the browser manually. When I try to access it with Axios from my React App I get CORS-Errors.
This is my react code:
     const swaggerUrl = 'https://localhost:44331/api/app/story/';
     const response = await axios.get(swaggerUrl);

Here are the error messages from Dev Tools:



In my Backend I configured the openIdDict like ABP.IO suggested with the OpenIdDictDataSeedContributor and also ran the migration:

And added the configuration values to the DBMigrator project.

Is there something I'm missing?
My react App runs locally on HTTP, but that shouldn't be a problem right?
Where else do I need to configure my ABP Backend to allow CORS?
I'd be super happy for any hints that push me in the right direction <3

I think you copied the migration code for "Web Client" and not "Console Test / Angular Client", there are differences there.
For testing, in your config file, try moving RootUrl from Storywise_Web_React_Viet section to Storywise_App and recreate the DB.
